# Dúvida sobre operadores lógicos && e || em Java

Tags: java, lógica

Eu tenho o seguinte código no meu aplicativo:

```
if (aquaName != null && !aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    values.put(NAME_COLUMN, aquaName.getText().toString().trim());
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Name cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Por que se eu usar `||` no lugar dos `&&` eu não atinjo a condição `else`?

Eu já li aqui no stack sobre `|` `&` `||` `&&` mas não consigo entender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A utilização do operador `&&` ou do operador `||` vai depender de suas condições.
O operador `&&` será utilizado quando todas as condições devem ser OBRIGATORIAMENTE verdadeiras, exemplo:

```
if(a && b && c && d){
    //Se todas forem verdade
}else{
   //Se qualquer delas foram mentira
}
```

Veja as letras `a`, `b`, `c` e `d` como sendo condições, logo se todas elas forem verdadeiras irá entrar no `if`, se ao menos uma delas não for verdadeira vai entrar no `else`.

Para o operador `||`, chamado de `OU`, permitirá entrar no `if` se ao menos uma condição for verdadeira, ou seja, se `a`, `b`, `c` ou `d` for verdadeiro entrará no `if`, se todos  foram falsos, entrará no `else`,exemplo:

```
if(a || b || c || d){
    //Se algumas (ao menos uma) for verdade
}else{
   //Se todas forem mentira (falsa)
}
```

Para  seu exemplo:

```
if (aquaName != null && !aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    values.put(NAME_COLUMN, aquaName.getText().toString().trim());
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Name cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

só entrará no `else` se `aquaName` for nulo e (`&&`) se for vazio.

Answer (score 4):

Porque `||` (ou) se qualquer uma das condições retornar `true` ele executa o `if`.

Exemplo:

```
aquaName = "" // (vazio)
aquaName != null // verdadeiro
!aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty() // falso
```

Executando seu if, já usando `&&` somente se todas as condições forem verdadeiras que ele executa seu if, se não cai no else.

Answer (score 1):

Por partes:

- `aquaName != null` vai ser verdadeiro se `aquaName` não for nulo, ou seja, tiver qualquer valor ("teste", " ", "", etc)
- `!aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty()` vai ser verdadeiro se for
  vazio (por conta do `!`).

Utilizando o `||`, entraria no `if` se uma das condições fosse verdadeira. Considerando o que você tem, se sua primeira condição for verdadeira, a segunda é falsa, e vice-versa.

---

Quanto aos operadores, utilizar um (`|` `&`) ou dois (`||` `&&`) "apenas" obriga a execução do que vem depois; usando como exemplo sua condição,

```
if (aquaName != null && !aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

Nesse caso, se `aquaName` for diferente de `null`, ele já entra no `if`. Usando apenas um operador,

```
if (aquaName != null & !aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

mesmo que `aquaName` seja igual a `null`, ele fará a validação `!aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty()`.

Sugiro você dar uma lida [nesse artigo](http://gabsferreira.com/operador-curto-circuito-e-if-ternario/), vai ajudar a entender bem quando usar esse tipo de comparador.

Answer (score 1):

`||` equivale a "ou" e `&&` equivale a "e"

na sua condição a primeira tem que ser diferente de null **E** a segunda diferente de vazio.

então as duas condições tem que ser verdadeira, se fosse usado `||` apenas uma já iria constar como verdadeiro.

Answer (score 1):

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremas_de_De_Morgan

Se você observar, o bloco `else` abriga uma mensagem dizendo que `Name cannot be empty`.

Logo, o bloco `if` deve abrigar um caso que

- seja a negação do caso `else`
- o bloco `else` deve executar se:

  - aquaName for nulo **OU**
  - o conteúdo de aquaName sem os espaços circundantes nele resultar numa string vazia

Por teorema de DeMorgan, ocorre a passagem da primeira para a segunda linha, abaixo:

```
NÃO (aquaName for nulo OU o conteúdo de aquaName sem os espaços circundantes nele não resultar numa string vazia) =

= NÃO (aquaName for nulo) E NÃO (o conteúdo de aquaName sem os espaços circundantes nele não resultar numa string vazia) =

= aquaName != null && !aquaName.getText().toString().isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as respostas já dadas, mas dando nome aos bois, `||` e `&&` são o que se chama de avaliação curto-circuito. Isso quer dizer que, se a primeira parte da expressão sendo avaliada (ou seja, a da esquerda) for verdadeiro para a expressão testada, a segunda parte da nem é checada.

```
String nome = "Luis";
int idade = 10;

if(nome == null && idade == 10) {
//não entra aqui
}
```

Para que o código de um bloco `if` seja executado, a expressão avaliada deve ser verdadeira (`true`). Quando se utiliza o operador `&&`, isso significa que ambos os lados devem ser `true` para que a expressão seja `true`. No exemplo, ao avaliar a primeira parte da expressão, `nome == null`, ela é falsa, então o compilador já sabe que não há mais como a expressão como um todo ser verdadeira (ambos os lados devem ser `true`, lembra-se?), logo, ele nem avalia o lado direito da expressão. É por isso que se chama curto-circuito, o compilador nem vai até o fim da avaliação, sai antes.

```
if(nome == null || idade == 10) {
//o código aqui dentro é executado
}
```

Uma avaliação com `||`, por sua vez, exige que apenas um dos lados da expressão seja `true` para que a expressão como um todo seja também `true`. Assim, `nome == null` é falso, mas como ainda há outro lado a ser avaliado e que pode ser `true`, o compilador o avalia também. Como `idade == 10` é verdadeiro, a expressão como um todo retorna `true` e o código dentro do `if` é executado.

Caso o primeiro lado já fosse `true` de cara, o compilador nem precisaria avaliar o outro lado, já que, como dito, com `||` basta um lado ser `true` para que a expressão como um todo também seja `true`. Seria novamente um curto-circuito.